# Du non-sens du mot « postérieur »

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps, indications-de-lieu

Quand on parle d'un événement postérieur à un autre, il s'agit d'un événement qui a eu lieu après l'autre événement. Inversement un événement antérieur à aujourd'hui est un événement qui relève du passé, et donc que l'on pourrait qualifier de *derrière* l'instant présent.

Dans ce cas là si ce qui est *derrière* peut être qualifié d'antérieur, **pourquoi appelle-t-on les fesses le postérieur ?**

Comment: De même les événements futurs sont _devant_ nous. Et quand je fais la queue à la caisse du supermarché, parmi tout ce qui est devant moi, il y a le postérieur du client précédent. On dirait du Devos...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Les membres postérieurs d'un animal se trouvent à l'arrière de celui-ci. Ils arrivent en dernier lorsqu'il avance ou qu'on le croise.

Ils sont donc biens postérieurs aux membres antérieurs qui eux arrivent/sont vus les premiers.

"Postérieur" désigne de manière plus générale ce qui est à l'arrière dans l'espace et après dans le temps.

Comment: Oui en fait ce qui cloche c'est le sens des mots antérieur/postérieur dans les contextes différents que sont la localisation spatiale et la localisation temporelle. Il ne faut pas faire de parallèles avec les mots devant/derrière sous peine de se tromper, mais plutôt avec les mots avant/après.

Comment: @Fractaliste ... plutôt *avant/arrière* lorsque l'on parle relativement du tronc, alors qu'on appelle habituellement les fesses *LE derrière* (car plus bas et à l'extrémité *arrière* du bipède qui se penche).