# Why do the transitive forms of “avancer” & “retarder” seem to have both opposite & identical meanings in the 4 nearly identical phrases below?

Tags: sens

Question in the “Title Header” restated in French:

« Pourquoi dans les 4 phrases suivantes, presque identiques, les verbes transitifs « avancer » et « retarder » semblent-ils avoir à la fois des sens opposés et identiques ? » :

> 1)    N’oubliez pas de retarder d’une heure votre rendez-vous le 26
>   octobre [de 14H a 15H, par exemple]. (C'est-à-dire que « retarder » =
>   une heure plus tard).
>
> 2)    N’oubliez pas de retarder d’une heure votre montre le 26 octobre
>   [de 3H a 2H, par exemple]. (C'est-à-dire que « retarder » = une heure
>   plus tôt).
>
> A)    N’oubliez pas d’avancer d’une heure votre rendez-vous le 29 mars
>   [de 14H a 13H, par exemple]. (C'est-à-dire que « avancer » = une heure
>   plus tôt).
>
> B)    N’oubliez pas d’avancer d’une heure votre montre le 29 mars [de 2H
>   a 3H, par exemple]. (C'est-à-dire que « avancer » = une heure plus
>   tard).

Autrement posée :

- Pourquoi est-ce que « avancer » (ou « retarder ») un *rendez-vous*
  signifie « plus tôt » (ou « plus tard »), mais « avancer » (ou «
  retarder ») *une montre* semble signifier l’idée contraire ?

Voilà une petite « sous-question » que je trouve pertinente qui m’est venue en formulant ma question:

- Si l’on parle des « réveils », soit des numériques ou des
  chronomètres, est-ce que l’action de les « retarder » ou « avancer »
  donne le même résultat que de retarder ou d’avancer une montre aux
  sens transitifs des 2 verbes dans lesdites phrases ‘2’ et ‘B’ ?

---

(Some background for my question ["Sorry," but the background is just in English]):

In English, there is some ongoing disagreement and confusion concerning the meaning of “moving up/forward” and moving back” when used to describe date and time changes.

Some, probably most, Anglophones claim that “moving up/forward” (advancer) means “to an EARLIER time” and that “moving back” (retarder) means “to a LATER time.”

However, there are many intelligent Anglophones who make logical arguments that the exact opposite is true (i.e., that “up/forward” = to a LATER time [in the future]; and that “back” = to an EARLIER time [in the past]).

My Francophone friends and family all claim that there is no similar disagreement and confusion in French because according to them, in French “advancer” always means EARLIER and “retarder” always means LATER.

In spite of their claims, however, none of them can explain and reconcile the contradictions contained in the above four assertions (or the sub-question concerning alarm clocks) without sounding at least a little bit confusing to me (just like Anglophones sound when we discuss the issue).

Even my normally trusty “Le Robert-Micro” seems to try to avoid the issue by simply (and cleverly) using the antonym of “retarder” (=advancer) instead of “plus tot” in its entry for “retarder une montre,” without ever clarifying which way is which within the confines of the entry itself:

> “Retarder … I. Verbe TRANSITIF … 2. Retarder une montre: la mettre à
>   une heure ‘moins avancée’ que celle qu’elle indique.”

Hopefully someone here can help me to reconcile the apparent contradictions that also appear to exist, at least to me, in French.

Thanking you all in 'advance' (whatever that means!).

Comment: C'est un problème de perception peut-être? Je peux t'assurer qu'au moment de changer l'heure pour l'heure d'été, beaucoup de gens sont confus quand on leur dit qu'ils doivent avancer l’heure. On se demande : donc il va faire claire plus tard ce soir ou si c'est le contraire? Normalement le dilemme est résolu après quelques secondes d'intenses réflexions mais je crois que cela prouve qu'il y a peut-être une ambiguïté.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lorsque l'on retarde une montre, on retarde le mouvement de l'aiguille, on le ralentit par rapport à l'heure officielle. On peut dire aussi que l'on arrête l'aiguille jusqu'à ce que la durée du retard à enregistrer soit écoulée - On se trouve dans le cas 2)

Pour l'avancer on fait évidemment le contraire - On se trouve dans le cas B).

Lorsqu'on retarde un rendez vous, on retarde l'heure officielle du rendez-vous, et pendant ce temps l'aiguille de la montre continue d’égrener les minutes ou les secondes, pour ajouter la durée du délai demandé à l'heure prévue initialement - On se trouve dans le cas 1).

Pour l'avancer on fait évidemment le contraire - On se trouve dans le cas A).

Ainsi selon que l'on considère *la position de l'aiguille* ou *l'heure choisie*, par le seul fait de se placer sur des points de vue opposés dans l'observation du même phénomène, le sens de l'action semble inversé.

En pratique on ajoute une durée avant ou après une heure fixée *à venir*, ou on positionne une heure en fonction de la durée à prendre en compte depuis *maintenant*.

Habituellement on dit :

> - Je serai en retard d'une heure pour ce rendez-vous, (retardez *l'heure choisie* pour le rendez-vous).

On pourrait dire :

> - Reculez votre montre d'une heure pour ce rendez-vous, (retardez *votre montre* d'une heure pour que nous nous rencontrions à l'heure choisie).

*Retarder* une *montre à aiguilles*  c'est *diminuer les nombres numériques* affichés par une *montre électronique*.

Answer (score 7):

Suivant que l'on se situe dans l'espace (aiguilles d'une montre) ou dans le temps (rendez-vous), les notions d'avant et après s'inversent.

**Avancer** une montre consiste à faire tourner physiquement les aiguilles **vers l'avant**, c'est à dire dans le sens de la marche des aiguilles.

Retarder une montre est le contraire, c'est à dire faire reculer les aiguilles.

**Avancer** un rendez vous consiste à le déplacer **avant l'heure** prévue, c'est à dire plus tôt.

Le retarder, c'est le déplacer plus tard, donc après l'heure prévue.

Voir cette question très similaire: [Du non-sens du mot « postérieur »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8393/du-non-sens-du-mot-post%C3%A9rieur/8396#8396)

Comment: Cette réponse est très bien synthétisée et me semble tout à fait claire et compréhensible. Bravo.

Answer (score 2):

*Être en avance*: signifie *"être `avant` l'heure"*
de là est née l'expression *"avancer un rendez-vous" c'est-à-dire le mettre `avant` l'heure prévue*.

*Être en retard*: signifie *"être `après` l'heure"*
de là est née l'expression *"retarder un rendez-vous" c'est-à-dire le mettre `après` l'heure prévue*.

Concernant le fait d'avancer ou de retarder une montre:

On dit qu'*une montre "avance"* quand elle `est en avance` sur le temps courant :
Les aiguilles se trouvent `après` leurs position normale.

A contrario, on dit qu'*une montre "retarde"* quand elle `est en retard` sur le temps courant :
Les aiguilles se trouvent `avant` leur position normale.

Nous voyons donc que lorsque l'on retarde une montre on déplace les aiguilles *`vers la gauche`* et lorsqu'on avance une montre on le fait *`vers la droite`*.

Ainsi, par exemple, lors du passage de l'heure d'été à l'heure d'hiver, les gens *retardent leurs montres* car ils gagnent une heure (la montre doit indiquer une heure de moins).
A contrario pour le passage de l'heure d'hiver à l'heure d'été, les gens perdent une heure, alors ils *avancent leurs montres* (la montre doit indiquer une heure de plus).

Answer (score 1):

Grosso modo, l'heure et le déplacement physique ont une notion de *avant* et d'*avancer* qui est différente. Elles n'entrent en conflit (à ma connaissance) que dans le cas précis auquel tu fais référence. Il est normal que le déplacement physique des aiguilles appelle automatique le sens physique et non-métaphorique rattaché à *avancer*.